# Sending GraphQL queries directly into MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, graphql

Newbie NodeJs developer here, trying to send GraphQL queries directly to MongoDB but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's the query resolver.

```
Query: {
  users: (_, { count }) =>  GetAllUsers((users) => users),
  user: (_, { id }) => GetUserByID(id, (user) => users),
},
```

I'm using callbacks in GetAllUsers

```
function GetAllUsers(callback) {
  MongoClient.connect(dbUrl, (err, client) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    let db = client.db("tbase");
    db.collection("Users", (err, coll) => {
      coll.find().toArray((err, items) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        return callback(items);
      })
    })
  })
}
```

and GetUserByID functions.

```
function GetUserByID(id, callback) {
  MongoClient.connect(dbUrl, (err, client) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    let db = client.db("tbase");
    db.collection("Users", (err, coll) => {
      coll.findOne({id: id}, (err, res) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        return callback(res);
      })
    })
  })
}
```

Both, GetAllUsers and GetUserByID functions take few seconds to load data, time which I do not really have as I'm instantly passing the result to GraphQL.

When I try something like this:

```
let usersArr;
GetAllUsers((users) => { usersArr = users; })
```

usersArr is undefined for a few seconds and then the data becomes accessible.

Now bear in mind that having worked in NET framework and MSSQL my whole life, this asynchronous stuff and NoSQL databases are pretty confusing for me.

Any help at all would be appreciated.

Comment: Where are you trying to **use** the `usersArr`?

Comment: I'm not trying to use usersArr anywhere. I just wrote it as an example that it takes few seconds to load data. All I'm trying to do is send GraphQL query directly to MongoDB by GetAllUsers and GetUserByID functions and their callbacks. Which (apparently) also takes few seconds to load and the object that I pass to GraphQL is null. As I've said, I'm pretty new to all this asynchronous stuff, so yeah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to do it with promises. Here's the code:

GetAllUsers:

```
const GetAllUsers = function(count) {
  let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    MongoClient.connect(dbUrl, (err, client) => {
      if(err) throw err;
      let db = client.db("tbase");
      db.collection("Users", (err, coll) => {
        coll.find().toArray((err, items) => {
          if(err) throw err;
          if(!count) resolve(items);
          if(count) resolve(items.slice(0, parseInt(count)));
        })
      })
    })
  });
  return promise;
}
```

GetUserByID

```
const GetUserByID = function(id) {
  let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    MongoClient.connect(dbUrl, (err, client) => {
      if(err) throw err;
      let db = client.db("tbase");
      db.collection("Users", (err, coll) => {
        coll.findOne({id: id}, (err, res) => {
          if(err) throw err;
          resolve(res);
        })
      })
    })
  });
  return promise;
}
```

Query resolver:

```
Query: {
      users: (_, { count }) =>  GetAllUsers(count, (users) => users),
      user: (_, { id }) => GetUserByID(id, (user) => users),
},
```

Answer (score 0):

> `usersArr` is undefined for a few seconds and then the data becomes accessible

"undefined" where? Yes, `let usersArr;` makes it undefined.

Also...

```
let usersArr;
GetAllUsers((users) => { usersArr = users; })
console.log(usersArr); // it is (probably) undefined here
```

You will only have the variable from within the callback, *after waiting* for the database&network request, hence the asynchronicity.

```
// let usersArr; // <--- this is the wrong pattern
GetAllUsers((users) => {
   // Every function that requires the data to be 
   // assigned must be called in here  
   console.log(users); 
})
// it is still undefined here
```

You can also define some other function as your callback

```
function logIt(data) {
    console.log(data);
}
GetAllUsers(logIt);
```

> worked in NET framework and MSSQL my whole life, this asynchronous stuff and NoSQL databases are pretty confusing for me.

I would argue that you should be familiar with threads and callback functions, and your database queries should not block the main thread. At least for UI applications. RDBMS queries can be asynchronous too.